# liferay: redirect visitor to different page if the user is not found in the autologin hook

Tags: liferay

I've created an autologin hook, and this works fine to log the user in.
However I'm now trying to redirect the user to a specific page on my portal in case the autologin fails (to localhost:8080/web/security/registerConditions).

However a response.sendRedirect to that URL seems to cause an infinite loop between the autologin and that page? Does anyone have any recommendations?
For now I think that liferay's autologin might set the http code and that's causing the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, if *all* URLs cause an anonymous session to redirect to some autologin url, this redirection loop will happen. You need to make sure that your /web/security/registerConditions page is available for anonymous users and doesn't trigger autologin.

A more specific answer would need more details about your implementation. You can try to look at Liferay's SSO-Filters to see how various single-sign-on-systems are integrated with Liferay.